# What is the meaning of this operator ?. in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this operator `?.` for the first time in a `react-native` project. What is this operator called and what does it do.

```
function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  const routeName = route.state?.routes[route.state.index]?.name ?? INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME;

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Home':
      return 'Home';
    case 'Links':
      return 'Links';
  }
}
```

Comment: is is called [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @NinaScholz, thanks for the link.